# ¿Por qué "We will have to inject some new talent " se traduce como "nuevos talentos" en plural?

Tags: plurales, inglés, categorías-gramaticales

Dada esta frase en inglés:

> We will have to inject some new talent in that store.

La veo traducida así:

> Tendremos que inyectar nuevos talentos en esa tienda.

¿Por qué dice *nuevos* si está en singular en su original inglés?

Comment: The new talent could be several people even though grammatically singular

Comment: ¿Dónde la ves traducida así?  Sin esta información, tengo que votar a cerrar.  (Si agregas esta información, cambio mi voto.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like translator license. In Spanish, *talento* means *innate skill* but it can also mean "a person with talent". In the latter meaning, it's always a countable noun. The translator seems to have decided that "injecting some new talent" means "bringing in people with new talents", so he had to use the plural.

The verb *inyectar* sounds awful to me, actually. You don't inject people into places. The sentence could very well have been translated simply as

> *Tendremos que inyectar talento nuevo en esa tienda.*

that is, preserving the uncountable abstract concept of "talent" as *talento*, or or better still, keeping it idiomatic (and cliché):

> *Tendremos que inyectarle una dosis de talento a esa tienda.*

Comment: I like your answer. Another option: *incorporar nuevos talentos a la tienda*.

Comment: Plural or singular, yes. *Incorporar* is much better than *inyectar*.

Comment: I agree but would go farther.  "New talent" means *new staff, new employees* or in, for example, the publishing world, *new authors, new clients to represent*.  Thus, I'd replace your "bringing in people with new talents" with "bringing in new people."  A cynic would say that fresh blood is good enough -- the new people don't need to necessarily be talented.  (New people often get paid less than those who've been in the organization for a long time.)

Answer (score 0):

Desde el momento que usas “some” en inglés estás hablando de la posibilidad de que sean más de uno. Entonces la traducción al español si o si deberá ser en plural.

Comment: What about "Let's buy some milk"?

Comment: @wimi Half a pint, a pint, two pints...?

Comment: @Traveller - I think wimi's point was that *talent* can be like water.  We might count the bottles of water, but the water itself doesn't get counted.

Comment: Bienvenida al sitio, Cecilia. // No me convence tu argumento.  Me parece que aquí "talento" es sinónimo de "personal."  Se necesita nuevo personal, pues.

Comment: @aparente001 Yes, I agree - same with milk! To me (a native English speaker) if I asked a friend to ‘pick me up some milk’ I’d be referring to an uncounted amount of milk. If I wanted to be precise I’d say ‘pick me up a pint (or two pints etc) of milk’.